# Can't install pandas==1.3.3 for python==3.7.15

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-3.7

My python version is `3.7.15`

I am setting up a `virtualenv` (`python3 -m venv env && source env/bin/activate`) and trying to install `pandas==1.3.3` but I get an error:

```
Collecting pandas==1.3.3
  Using cached pandas-1.3.3.tar.gz (4.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/user/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/user/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/Users/user/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/private/var/folders/yq/l3rq2lw55t923sygld_4m2rm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nre30lmt/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "/private/var/folders/yq/l3rq2lw55t923sygld_4m2rm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nre30lmt/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 320, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/yq/l3rq2lw55t923sygld_4m2rm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nre30lmt/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 484, in run_setup
          self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "/private/var/folders/yq/l3rq2lw55t923sygld_4m2rm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nre30lmt/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 18, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/user/env/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Do you have any ideas, what is wrong? I have tried to update `pip` version `pip install -U pip` but the result was the same

Comment: Which version of Numpy do you have. Mine is 1.21.0 and I am getting the same exact error after I install Numpy. I am installing it with a python version of 3.10.6. I have also tried to update `pip` but no effect happens. But when installing the  `2.0.1` the error is gone.